# Master Equation under a classical fluctuating noise

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I have a system as a qubit with Hamiltonian
$H_S = \frac{\Delta}{2}\sigma_z$
The interaction Hamiltonian is
$H_I = \frac{V(t)}{2}\sigma_z$ where $V(t)$ is a stochastic fluctuating variable. One can for example assume it as a random telegraph noise(RTN). In this case, what is the general prescription to write down the master equation for the qubit?

Comment: It seems a bit strange that the interaction terms also contains $\sigma_z$. I would have expected $\sigma_x$ or $\sigma_y$. Is it perhaps a typo?

Comment: No, it is $\sigma_z$. I am looking for a general method to write down master equation under various $V(t)$ gaussian or non-gaussian.

Answer (score 2):

There is a procedure outlined here: A. A. Budini, "Non-Markovian Gaussian dissipative stochastic wave vector", [*Phys. Rev. A* **63**, 012106 (2000)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.63.012106).

You basically take an ensemble average over the noise realizations, and use some techniques from functional calculus. It is based on Gaussian noises, but you can extend it to non-Gaussian noises too, however you will not reach a Lindblad-like master equation.

You can also see my paper, which is based on the above reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.02628

The derivation is in section III.B (it is severely shortened though), and the key point is Eq. 49. If you want to use non-Gaussian noises, that equation has a generalization in

F. Moss and P. McClintock, Noise in Nonlinear Dynamical Systems:
Volume 1, Theory of Continuous Fokker-Planck SystemsRef. (Look for Eq. 9.4.1).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any prescription without resorting to the method of stochastic unravelings in deriving the master equation?

Answer (score 2):

[The book by Klyatskin](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-07587-7) discusses general functional methods for dealing with gaussian and telegraph noises.

However, let me make a few general remarks:

- Telegraph noise is not delta-correlated (white), which means that one would get an integral equation, rather than usual master equation.
- Including noise as an external force, without taking into account its respose to the qubit dynamics, breakes the fluctuation-dissipation theorem. Thus, the resulting equation will not contain dissipative/relaxation terms (again, it is not a master equation, properly speaking).
- Writing a master equation for a two-level system is a bit of overkill, since Bloch equations are enough for a two-level system.